# GUI for editing image metadata

Tags: images, metadata, exif

Is there a graphical application for editing image metadata in EXIF, IPTC and XMP formats?
Preferably free and for Windows.

Some image editors and the Windows Explorer properties window allow editing of some metadata but also destroy other metadata.
The exiv2 command line tool is very reliable in this area, but surely there must be a good graphical program out there too?

Comment: You can do it with PhotoShop: http://www.peachpit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=photoshop&seqNum=279

Comment: @Dynamic: and you can also play music with combination of vi and X server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xnview](http://www.xnview.com) if I remember correctly. Knows lots of formats. And very flexible.

Comment: I tried this out, looks good so far. It allows me to edit all of the EXIF, IPTC and XMP fields that I need in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Another free one that looks good is [PhotoME](http://www.photome.de/). Did you try this one?

[image]

Comment: This does not support XMP.

Comment: If it's XMP that you want, then there's only one good solution - Adobe's Photoshop. Unlike EXIF & IPTC, XMP is an de-facto standard. Meaning that it was invented by Adobe and it evolves with each new release of Photoshop, which given its dominant position, the industry has no choice but to adjust. In other words, the only real definition of XMP is what Photoshop does. In my job we often receive images edited by other software than Photoshop and have to correct illegal XMP contents. Such is life.

Answer (score 0):

Just google for "exif editor" and you will find a zillion of them.
A good one is [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.html). As said above, IrfanView is also good.

Comment: I have tried very many that I found using Google, but none were good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The [**ExifTool**](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is beautiful work by **Phil Harvey**.

If you scroll over near the bottom of that link,
there is a section called "**Related Utilities**"
which has references to other utilities using the ExifTool engine.
There are **some GUI application in that list that might interest you**.

Check [**ExifDropper**](http://fliggs.wordpress.com/) and [**ExifTool**](http://freeweb.siol.net/hrastni3/foto/exif/exiftoolgui.htm) [GUI](http://freeweb.siol.net/hrastni3/).
Comment here if you like any one of these in particular.

Comment: ExifTool GUI does not allow me to edit IPTC.DateCreated for example.

Comment: As far as I can tell, ExifDropper does not let you view metadata within a file. Perhaps it is useful for those who already know how to use ExifTool.

Answer (score 0):

[PixVue](http://www.photo-freeware.net/pixvue.php) does an outstanding job with this, but the website and project seems to have gone dormant. It still works though.

Comment: It claims to edit IPTC and XMP, but I see no mention of EXIF.

Answer (score 0):

Gwenview of kde. There's a [KDE Windows Initiative](http://www.windows.kde.org) - so it works under windows. In gwenview it's under Plugins -> Tools -> Edit all metadata. You'll also might need to install kipi-plugins.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

IrfanView + plugins = Super awesome image viewer + manipulator + info editor. Try this one.

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but unfortunately it only allows editing of a limited set of IPTC fields.