# A software to view/edit image meta data and copyright details?

Tags: images, metadata, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GUI for editing image metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/34320/gui-for-editing-image-metadata)

Hi,

I've got a bunch of good looking photos both natural and digital graphics, and most of them don't seem to contain any copyright details. I'm always ready to switch the photos I use if someone is going to complain about using their photos, but I'd like to avoid that and try to view some file meta data hidden copyright details if such thing exist?

For example, in Photoshop when I "save for web", and I choose PNG, it has this "include copyright details" - what are those specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/34320/gui-for-editing-image-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably just additional details added into the EXIF data, which you would see when viewing the data in a capable program:

[image]

there are a number of tools you can use to view EXIF data, such as [EXIF Image Viewer](http://home.pacbell.net/michal_k/exif_v.html), and for editing, [EXIFEditor](http://www.kiwiczech.net/index.php?menu=353&sub=4), although you haven't indicated the operating system you're running :)